# How to make jquery counter work with data from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

I am trying to make a counter using jquery. This counter works when data is passed into the `div` directly, but does not work when this data is dynamically appended to the `div` using `.innerHTML` call.

Below I have the counter code applied to all elements of `.count` class and I want this counter to work on the `div` with id = "users" using the `document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;` This does not work.

But the following works: `<div id="users" class="count">300</div>`

```
$('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
     });
```

```html
<div id="users" class="count"></div>

document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;
```

The output I get while using `document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;` is 0, but this is unexpected. I have several elements with class `count` that depend on this counter.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Ben you need to set the innerHTML before you call the counter animation 
document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;

$('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to write `document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;` before the `.each` code, because `.innerHTML` works for me

```js
document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;
$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users" class="count"></div>
```

Or you could add `DOMSubtreeModified` event, so when the sub-tree is changed your function will be triggered (`one` is to trigger the event once as we don't want sub-tree event to fire again):

```js
$('.count').one("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 5000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = 300;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users" class="count"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what is meant by "I want this counter to work...", but does this handle your use case?:

```js
const users = document.getElementById("users");
users.innerHTML = "300";
//users.addEventListener("change", console.log(users.innerHTML));

$('.count').each(function () {
  let num = users.innerHTML; // Sets the value dynamically
  $(this).prop('Counter', num).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="users" class="count">0</p>
```